# Attribute table of GPKG layer does not allow to edit

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I created a GPKG layer whose name is `Grid 1`. In database, I wrote a `trigger`,because when attribute table of layer is changed, another table value should be changed also -They have common id's.

However, when I try to edit the attribute table, I can not edit it. Here is my update trigger code:

```
self.execSql("CREATE TRIGGER 'ibound_trigger1' AFTER UPDATE OF ibound ON 'Grid1' BEGIN UPDATE 'Yas_Veri' SET ibound = NEW.ibound WHERE cell_id = NEW.cell_id; END;")
```

`Grid1`: GPKG layer on canvas (triggers Yas_Veri table)

`Yas_Veri`: Table in my database (triggered from Grid1)

`ibound` : column name (common for both table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of primary key. The table has to have primary key.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer! You earned it!